# Rate of descent of a hot air-balloon

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

A rope is attached to the bottom of a hot air-balloon that is floating above a flat field. If the angle of the rope to the ground remains at 65 degrees and the rope is pulled in at 5 ft/s, how quickly is the elevation of the ballon changing?

Answer (score 1):

Since the angle is constantly 65 degrees, you can just use trigonometry to solve for the vertical difference $x$:
$$\sin(65^{\circ}) = \frac{5}{x} \Rightarrow x = 5\sin(65^{\circ}) \approx 4.53 ft/s$$

Answer (score 1):

Let length of rope between ground and balloon be $r$.  We are given that 
$\frac{dr}{dt} = -5 \mbox{ ft/s}$. The elevation of the balloon is $Cr$, where constant $C = \sin(65^{\circ}).$

The elevation of balloon is changing at rate 
$$ \begin{align}
\frac{d(Cr)}{dt} & = C \frac{dr}{dt} \mbox{ since $C$ is constant} \\
& = -5C \mbox{ ft/s}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Leaving very little for OP to do.